# What do Jews have against hammans?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Recently, I have been hearing a lot of talk about [hammans](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g293734-i9196-k4287618-Hamman_what_does_it_consist_of-Marrakech_Marrakech_Tensift_El_Haouz_Region.html). I found this picture and it looks like a [nice place](http://promet.com.tr/en/urunler-turk_hamami.html). So why do Jews always boo when you say it? Is it like against the Torah

[image]

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: This DOES look like a nice place. But, for you ... I suggest that you recommend that your local mikvah should install a sauna and or steam room. I wonder why none of these places have that. Come to think of it, a massagist would be a nice touch, also.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this article](http://www.enjoythemomentrituals.com/history-of-hammam/) there is an entire ritual that occurs in the hammam. The site says:

> It was and still is in some villages not only a retreat for bodily
>   and spiritual cleansing

Bodily cleansing is not a problem in halacha. (There may be other halachic problems specifically with the hamam if nude men and women are there together. I don't really know if that occurs.)

The bigger problem is the "spiritual cleansing". One of the purposes of the hammam is to cleanse you of your faith and spirit in G-d and make you an atheist! That's contrary to Judaism. That's why we boo when you hear the mention of a hammam.

Answer (score 2):

[The Gemara in Chullin 139b](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%97%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9F_%D7%A7%D7%9C%D7%98_%D7%91) says that the source of Hammans is the tree of knowledge. Obviously it looks good, Chava herself thought that it was good because it looked good as the [Passuk in Bereishis 3:6](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94:%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%92_%D7%95) says.

We scream and yell to make sure no one gives in just because it looks good.

**STAY AWAY!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!**